# What Joins to use to join multiple tables together into one view

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

I have a db in mysql with multiple tables and would like to join multiple tables into one view to save me from having to build 3 or 4 sql statements or even one large joining statement in php to get the same info.

Here are all my tables that I want to join

```
track_title               
+----+------------------+
| ID |      TITLE       |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | Title Here       |
|  2 | Another Title    |
|  3 | Some Other Title |
+----+------------------+

track_artist
+----+----------------+-----------+-----------+
| ID | TRACK_TITLE_ID | ARTIST_ID | SYMBOL_ID |
+----+----------------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | 1              | 1         | 2         |
| 2  | 1              | 2         | 1         |
| 3  | 3              | 1         | 1         |
+----+----------------+-----------+-----------+

artist

+----+-------------+
| ID | ARTIST      |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | Linkin Park |
| 2  | Metallica   |
+----+-------------+

symbol
+----+--------+
| ID | SYMBOL |
+----+--------+
| 1  |        |
| 2  | Feat.  |
+----+--------+

tracklisting
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+
| ID | TRACK NO | TITLE_ID | VERSION       | DISC NO |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+
| 1  | 1        | 1        |               | 1       |
| 2  | 1        | 2        | Album Version | 1       |
| 3  | 1        | 3        | Live Version  | 1       |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+---------+
```

This is the final view I'm looking for

```
+----+----------+------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+---------+
| ID | TRACK NO | TITLE            | VERSION       | ARTIST                      | DISC NO |
+----+----------+------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+---------+
| 1  | 1        | Title Here       |               | Linkin Park Feat. Metallica | 1       |
| 2  | 1        | Another Title    | Album Version |                             | 1       |
| 3  | 1        | Some Other Title | Live Version  | Linkin Park                 | 1       |
+----+----------+------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+---------+
```

I have been bashing my head for the past 3 days with left, right, join and full join and just can't seem to get this to work.

Basically what I want to happen is the track_artist table will get the artist and symbol form the respective tables and concat them together into one column. Then join title and the concat column to have this view.

```
full_artist_view
+----------+------------------+-----------------------------+
| TITLE_ID | TITLE            | FULL_ARTIST                 |
+----------+------------------+-----------------------------+
| 1        | Title Here       | Linkin Park Feat. Metallica |
| 2        | Another Title    |                             |
| 3        | Some Other Title | Linkin Park                 |
+----------+------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I have gotten this far but when I try join this to the tracklisting table I seem to crash my server which is getting very painful. No mysql error so I'm guessing I'm using the wrong join or this is just not possible.(though I can't see how this is not possible)

The tracklisting table is continuesly growing every week by 1000 records comfortable and is sitting at +- 75000 records.

To me this is the sql that should work, but doesn't

```
FROM full_artist_view LEFT JOIN tracklisting ON 
full_artist_view.TITLE_ID = tracklisting.TITLE_ID
```

Comment: Can you post your code for the `full_artist_view`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I have only your small data sample and I can't see what your `full_artist_view` code looks like.  You should be able to get the result using the following:

```
select tt.id,
  tl.`track no`,
  tt.title,
  coalesce(tl.version, '') version,
  group_concat(concat(coalesce(a.artist, ''), ' ', coalesce(s.symbol, '')) order by a.artist SEPARATOR ' ') artist,
  tl.`disc no`
from track_title tt
inner join tracklisting tl
  on tt.id = tl.TITLE_ID
left join track_artist ta
  on tt.id = ta.TRACK_TITLE_ID
left join artist a
  on ta.artist_id = a.id
left join symbol s
  on ta.symbol_id = s.id
group by tt.id, tl.`track no`, tt.title, tl.version, tl.`disc no`
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0478a/24). This returns:

```
| ID | TRACK NO |            TITLE |       VERSION |                       ARTIST | DISC NO |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |        1 |       Title Here |               | Linkin Park Feat. Metallica  |       1 |
|  2 |        1 |    Another Title | Album Version |                              |       1 |
|  3 |        1 | Some Other Title |  Live Version |                 Linkin Park  |       1 |
```

Comment: This works perfect with a few records like here as an example, 70000 + records and crash. I think the joins become to intense with large recordsets like this. Unless theres something I'm missing

Comment: @Mark What indexes do you have on your tables? What does the explain plan say?

Comment: I May have forgotten to put indexes on my columns. Once I added the indexes it worked perfect. Thanks for all the help

Comment: @Mark I am glad you figured it out!  Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick play, and I think (but not certain) it is something like this that you need:-

```
SELECT a.Id, a.Track_No, b.Title, a.Version, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(d.Artists, e.Symbol)), a.Disc_No
FROM tracklisting a
INNER JOIN track_title b ON a.Title_id = b.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN track_artist c ON b.Id = c.Track_Title_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN artist d ON c.Artist_Id = d.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN symbol e ON d.SymbolId = e.Id
GROUP BY a.Id, a.Track_No, b.Title, a.Version, a.Disc_No
```

But I might have missed something so let me know!